# PHP use array_merge_recursive() when each array is stored in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 separate arrays which are stored in one big array like so:

```
$date = '2017-08-01';

$price_arr_1 = array();
$price_arr_1[$date]['adult_1'] = 10;
$price_arr_1[$date]['child_1'] = 2;

$price_arr_2 = array();
$price_arr_2[$date]['adult_2'] = 10;
$price_arr_2[$date]['child_2'] = 2;

$price_arr_3 = array();
$price_arr_3[$date]['adult_3'] = 10;
$price_arr_3[$date]['child_3'] = 2;

$multiple_arrays[] = $price_arr_1;
$multiple_arrays[] = $price_arr_2;
$multiple_arrays[] = $price_arr_3;

print_r($multiple_arrays);
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [2017-08-01] => Array ( [adult_1] => 10 [child_1] => 2 ) ) [1] => Array ( [2017-08-01] => Array ( [adult_2] => 10 [child_2] => 2 ) ) [2] => Array ( [2017-08-01] => Array ( [adult_3] => 10 [child_3] => 2 ) ) )
```

I want to use array_merge_recursive() to merge the three arrays into one like this:

```
Array ( [2017-08-01] => Array ( [adult_1] => 10 [child_1] => 2 [adult_2] => 10 [child_2] => 2 [adult_3] => 10 [child_3] => 2 ) )
```

I think looping through the main array might work, but I can't get my head around it, appreciate any help!

I can't do the following because the number of arrays within the array is different each time:

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive($multiple_arrays[0],$multiple_arrays[1],$multiple_arrays[2]));
```

Comment: it will still work, isn't it?

Comment: You mean the last part where I'm using $multiple_arrays[0],$multiple_arrays[1]... ? The number of arrays in the array changes each time, so no it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass to `array_merge_recursive` several arguments you can use `call_user_func_array`. In your case it will look like:

```
$date = '2017-08-01';

$price_arr_1 = array();
$price_arr_1[$date]['adult_1'] = 10;
$price_arr_1[$date]['child_1'] = 2;

$price_arr_2 = array();
$price_arr_2[$date]['adult_2'] = 10;
$price_arr_2[$date]['child_2'] = 2;

$price_arr_3 = array();
$price_arr_3[$date]['adult_3'] = 10;
$price_arr_3[$date]['child_3'] = 2;

$multiple_arrays[] = $price_arr_1;
$multiple_arrays[] = $price_arr_2;
$multiple_arrays[] = $price_arr_3;

//print_r($multiple_arrays);

$r = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $multiple_arrays);
print_r($r);
```